# Facebook native ios login error with test user

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I'm getting the following error when attempting to use the ios6 native facebook login

```
The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Temporarily unable to make API calls on behalf of XYZ
```

The login works fine if I remove the ios facebook user from settings and use the webview style of login rather than the built in ios way.  It also works if I don't use the fb test user.  I've checked the test user's permissions and it has all the read and write permissions.  Are test users not allowed to use the native ios login?

Is this an error on Facebook's servers?  How can I further diagnose this?

here's the full error output

```
2013-03-24 10:45:57.701 HelloFacebookSample[39800:19a03] FBLoginView encountered an error=Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0xa288a00 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Temporarily unable to make API calls on behalf of 10000000" UserInfo=0xa157760 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Temporarily unable to make API calls on behalf of 10000000}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0xa27e530, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 20000000, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0xa2742c0>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}
```

I am using a test facebook user that has been added to the testers group of the app

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue? I am facing the same problem!

Comment: From what I can tell, test users cannot use the native ios facebook login

Comment: We seem to have encountered this problem as well. If we log into Facebook via iOS Settings with a Facebook test account, it fails with the error that looks something like: "Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 'The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Temporarily unable to make API calls on behalf of XXXX'". Very frustrating since it took us a while to figure out what exactly was going on but when we use a valid, real FB account it authenticates properly. Hopefully this will get fixed in an update to iOS 6 or in iOS 7, but I'm not holding my breath...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have yet enough reputation to vote, but MonkeyBonkey is right. I was having the same issue, change the Facebook's test user to other "real" Facebook user and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You can login to an app using a test user as long as the app is set to 'live'.  To do that, go here https://developers.facebook.com/apps and click on 'Status & Review' then make sure the switch is set to 'On'.  If it's grayed out, just hover over it with your mouse and it will tell you want you need to do to make it live, I was missing a contact email.

If you want to create test users, go to 'Roles' then the 'Test Users' tab.

Hope that helps someone.